# Laravel Queue with Schedule (Laravel 7x)

Tags: laravel, queue, schedule

I'm trying to dive in Laravel Queue. In my example I have a (Daily~)QuoteController with a function choose, that chooses a quote rand:

```
public function choose()
    {
        $quote = Quote::all()->random(1)->first();
        return $quote;
    }
```

and a function send, to dispatch a SendReportingEmail-Job

```
public function send() {
    $content =  QuoteController::choose();  
    //Log::info("Request Cycle with Queues Begins");
    $this->dispatch( new SendReportingEmail($content) );
    //Log::info("Request Cycle with Queues Ends");     
}
```

In the Job SendReportingEmail I use a constructor to get the Content

```
class SendReportingEmail implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
    private $content;
    public function __construct($content)
    {
        $this->content = $content;
    }
    
    public function handle(Mailer $mailer)
    {
        ... send E-Mail
    }
```

So far, so good - queue is working. Now I'd like to schedule this job every 5 minutes so I added to Kernel.php

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        
        $schedule->job(new SendReportingEmail(???how to pass $content for Job???), 'reportingemail')->everyFiveMinutes();
    }
```

What is the best way to get the working?
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO ... your job should be the thing that queries the database to get the random record, then no data needs to be passed

Comment: Thank you, worked fine

Answer (score 0):

**Create an artisan command is a better solution.**

In app\Console\Kernel:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('email:send')->everyFiveMinutes();
}
```

In your artisan command class:

```
/**
* Execute the console command.
*
* @return mixed
*/
public function handle(ReportingEmailService $service)
{
    $service->send(); // the send() method you mentioned in your question
}
```